# setData command is not setting my data to CKEDITOR everytime

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
          CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        contentsCss: '../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        toolbar:
            [
                { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'], items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates'] },
                { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'], items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
                { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'], items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt', 'ImageButton'] },
                { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
                '/',
                { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
                { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language'] },
                '/',
                { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
                { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
                { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe', 'ShowBlocks'] }
            ]
    });



    MyAjaxMethod('GetDatabyId', IdParam, function (data) {
        var dt = data.d;
        if (dt!= null) {


            $("#foo").html(dt.asd);
            $("#foo2").val(dt.asdf);
            $("#foo3").val(dt.asdfg);

            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(dt.Detay);

        }
        else {
            alert('no data');
        }
    });
```

It needs to get data and set some formtools and finally set CKEDITOR, but it sometimes doesnt set data to CKEDITOR and sometimes does. I tried a simple page with same ajax method and scripts but it didnt work why can it be? I can see all data incoming, json is fine. I tried to send to CKEDITOR's html and inserthtml that also didnt work. I thought it tries to set before it replace CKEDITOR feautures, but i couldnt do anything about it.

Edit: How can i fix that problem? (clarifying my specific problem)

Edit2: Thanks to [ojovirtual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979648/ojovirtual) and [torun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367006/torun) found problem, it was being sure of that instance is ready before setting data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `setData` only when the instance is ready. It works only sometimes because when you call `setData` the `CKEDITOR` is not fully initialized sometimes and some others it is.

There is a event called `instanceReady` that you can use to set the data:

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event)
{
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(dt.Detay);
});
```

[CKEDITOR docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#event:instanceReady)

Answer (score 1):

You should try, create the function for preparation part, try to run before setData.

```
function prepCkeditor()
{
          CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        contentsCss: '../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        toolbar:
            [
                { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'], items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates'] },
                { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'], items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
                { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'], items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt', 'ImageButton'] },
                { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
                '/',
                { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
                { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language'] },
                '/',
                { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
                { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
                { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe', 'ShowBlocks'] }
            ]
    });
}
```

You have to be sure it works before the above code.

```
prepCkeditor();
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(dt.Detay);
```